# How to access dundle method from a subclass in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, private-methods

I there a way to directly access dundle method in sub-class of Python ?

Imagine I have the following classes :

```py
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    
    def __add(self,y):
        return self.x + y
    
    def addition(self,y):
        return self.__add(y)

class Children(Parent):
    
    def add(self,y):
        return self.__add(y)
```

I can obviously instantiate the two classes, and use `addition` on both, but I can't use `add` from instance of `Children`. How could I access `__add` method inherited from `Parent` class to `Children` class ?

```py
p = Parent(2)
p.addition(4)

c = Children(5)
c.addition(4)
```

all these calls work, but the two below don't

```py
p.__add(5)  # AttributeError: 'Parent' object has no attribute '__add'
c.add(4)  # AttributeError: 'Children' object has no attribute '_Children__add'
```

And both return absence of attribute. The first behavior is the expected one, I do not want to change, but the second one is disturbing to me, since a sub-class should be able to access its parent hidden method, shouldn't it ?

More details : in fact the parent class in my case are dealing with a DB connection, and deal with username and passwords, with some method to check the password `__check_password` that I prefer to let 'private'. I'd like to call `__check_password` from different child classes, that deal with data manipulation later.

Comment: `return self._Parent__add(y)`? See [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Comment: The entire point of `__private` is to *prevent* access from child classes. While access is still possible, *why do you want this*? The simplest approach is just *not* to use a `__private` method but rather one that is `_protected` or `public`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your comment. I already explained _why I want this_ in my question.

Comment: @FraSchelle The question currently just says you prefer to let `__check_password` be private then immediately say you prefer *not* to use it as private. I was hoping for an actual reason, not a restatement of the apparent contradiction.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'd like the attribute/method to be hidden at the level of the Parent and the Children classes, yet to be transmissible from one to the other in a hidden way. Thank you for pointing me in the right normenclature :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you, it indeed explain that I should not try to hide anything that way in Python. So the answer to my question is 'yes it's possible' ...

Comment: ...and that's @Axe319 's comment. Thank you very much to both of you !